# Forced Reflow inside chained function not happening in js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to implement jquery in js. I want reflow and repaint to take place after every chained function for which I'm using innerText but reflow and repaint aren't taking place and I'm seeing last state after all chained functions have executed. How can I achieve the expected behaviour. Also for implementing delay function i'm blocking the main thread by using while loop, is that the best away to go about it?

```
<div id="el" class="myDiv">
  el
</div>

.myDiv{
  width:50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.big{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.red{
  background:red
}

function $(query){
    let obj = Object.create($.prototype)
    obj.el = document.querySelector(`${query}`);
    return obj;
}


$.prototype.addClass=function(name){
        this.el.classList.add(name)
        this.el.innerText
    return this
}
$.prototype.removeClass= function(name){
  this.el.classList.remove(name)
  this.el.innerText
  return this
}
$.prototype.delay=function(time){
    this.el.innerText
  let stamp = new Date().getTime();
  while(new Date().getTime() - stamp < time);
  
  return this;
}

let x = $('#el').delay(2000).addClass('big').delay(2000).addClass('red').removeClass('big');
```

**EDIT: To all the viewers please at least upvote the question if you are not able to answer so that it gets the visibility and is answered. Thank You!**

Comment: How do I unsee this? Blocking the main thread is NEVER ok. You should look into `Promise` and `async` as well as `await`. Also we are in 2021 now. Use a `class` instead of prototypes.

Comment: @GottZ I had not used the class because then I had to declare objects via new keyword but I wanted the implementation to look as close as to that of jquery. I do know about promises and async and await but all the chained functions should execute in sequence therefore I must do synchronous execution.

Comment: jQuery itself also creates a instance of jQuery. There is nothing wrong in doing that too.